# PHP Trait on child class doesn't work

Tags: php, traits

I have class A with "`auditable`" trait, which has sub class B and sub class C, if i instantiate Class C trait doesn't work. Class C only have "getNameAttribute" mutator for getting data, nothing more. And there is no problem on saving object

```
class A {
   use auditable;
}

class B extends A {
   // Trait Works in this one
}

class C extends B {
   // Trait Doesn't work
   public function getNameAttribute($val)
   {
      return Str::upper($val);
   }

}
```

any solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work". Post the error message.

Comment: It does nothing, no error message events didn't fired

Comment: Then it's not a problem with the trait, but something else. It would be really weird your B class get the functions of trait but not you C class. Show more of your code

Comment: did you check the log? Do you have APP_DEBUG=TRUE in your .env file?

Comment: log is on and nothing is written here for this case

Comment: when I get problems like this (and I don't have tests for the code), I'll use `dd()` in various places to see where the code is breaking. Try adding `dd(true)` to the trait method then calling it again, seeing if it outputs `true`. If it doesnt, keep adding `dd()` in relevant places until you can get an error message / change the error message.

Comment: I tried it doesn't fire event for trait

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] - as it is, the code you have shown is incomplete, and doesn't reproduce the problem, as shown in [Vladimir Kovpak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50391509/157957) and [this online demo](https://3v4l.org/HItqc). There is presumably some detail in class `C` that is stopping whatever the `auditable` trait does from working as you expect, and without seeing more code (but not your whole application please!) we could sit here all year guessing at what that is.

Comment: @IMSoP edited as you said

Comment: Sorry, but that's still not *complete*, or *verifiable* - What is `Str::upper`? What is in the `auditable` trait? What code are you running that is not working as expected - that is, how are you using classes `B` and `C`? What is the trait supposed to do that it is not doing? You've probably been staring at this problem for some time, but remember that we have *only the information you give us*, none of your other code, and none of your previous attempts to test and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from traits: actually it works, look:

```
<?php

trait auditable {
    public function foo()
    {
        return 'Bar';
    }
}

class A {
    use auditable;
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends B {
}

var_dump((new C())->foo());
```

If you run this scrip - you get: `string(3) "Bar"`

In your case it means that you have error in another place, and to find it out you have to enable error log. You can try to do something like this:

```
// add in your index.php (or bootstrap file)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors','On');
```

Comment: Error log shows nothing, no errors are thrown in laravel log file